# Make command run with no gui if can't connect to Xserver

Tags: java, bash, server, minecraft, xserver

I run minecraft server (spigot using openjdk 11) on a headless machine using UNIX screen through ssh. I can connect to an Xserver on an alternate machine to show the proper gui. My bash script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=$@
while true
do
java -server -Xmx1400M -Xms1100M -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=45 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:G1NewSizePercent=50 -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=80 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=10 -XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=50 -XX:+AggressiveOpts -jar spigot-1.16.1.jar
echo restarting in 5 seconds. Ctrl-C to cancel.
sleep 5
done
```

I run it like this:`$ ./start.sh 192.168.x.x:y` where x.x are the 2 numbers for the local ip and y is the X11 port. I can also use a hostname.

This works seamlessly while the Xserver is running

My problem is that when the Xserver stops (e.g. I close my laptop), it gives an error instead of running headlessly:

```java
OpenJDK Server VM warning: Option AggressiveOpts was deprecated in version 11.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Loading libraries, please wait...
[17:28:09] [main/INFO]: Environment: authHost='https://authserver.mojang.com', accountsHost='https://api.mojang.com', sessionHost='https://sessionserver.mojang.com', name='PROD'
[17:28:13] [main/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default, bukkit
[17:28:20] [Worker-Main-4/INFO]: Loaded 7 recipes
[17:28:31] [main/INFO]: [STDERR]: java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using '192.168.1.1:1' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
[17:28:31] [main/INFO]: [STDERR]:   at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
[17:28:31] [main/INFO]: [STDERR]:   at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:102)
[17:28:31] [main/INFO]: [STDERR]:   at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[17:28:31] [main/INFO]: [STDERR]:   at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:61)
[17:28:31] [main/INFO]: [STDERR]:   at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[17:28:31] [main/INFO]: [STDERR]:   at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
[17:28:31] [main/INFO]: [STDERR]:   at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:101)
[17:28:31] [main/INFO]: [STDERR]:   at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE.<clinit>(GraphicsEnvironment.java:83)
[17:28:31] [main/INFO]: [STDERR]:   at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:129)
[17:28:31] [main/INFO]: [STDERR]:   at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:232)
[17:28:31] [main/INFO]: [STDERR]:   at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[17:28:31] [main/INFO]: [STDERR]:   at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
[17:28:31] [main/INFO]: [STDERR]:   at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:588)
[17:28:31] [main/INFO]: [STDERR]:   at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:583)
[17:28:31] [main/INFO]: [STDERR]:   at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[17:28:31] [main/INFO]: [STDERR]:   at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:582)
[17:28:31] [main/INFO]: [STDERR]:   at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName(UIManager.java:661)
[17:28:31] [main/INFO]: [STDERR]:   at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.ServerGUI.a(ServerGUI.java:44)
[17:28:31] [main/INFO]: [STDERR]:   at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.DedicatedServer.bb(DedicatedServer.java:430)
[17:28:31] [main/INFO]: [STDERR]:   at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.Main.lambda$2(Main.java:181)
[17:28:31] [main/INFO]: [STDERR]:   at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:170)
[17:28:31] [main/INFO]: [STDERR]:   at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.Main.main(Main.java:169)
[17:28:31] [main/INFO]: [STDERR]:   at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.Main.main(Main.java:202)
[17:28:31] [Thread-1/INFO]: Stopping server
[17:28:31] [Thread-1/INFO]: Saving worlds
restarting in 5 seconds. Ctrl-C to cancel.
```

Is it possible to make the server run headlessly (ie just through an ssh client) when the Xserver is offline?

I'd prefer it to be a bash solution as I don't know any java. Flags for the (java) command would be even better!

Comment: Does this help? https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/headless.html

Comment: @Abra No; I want a solution that works in bash while leaving java alone. This is probably more to do with openjdk flags. I could try something like pinging the target xserver but I don't know how to get a boolean from that.